# Date time to Epoch conversion

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, epoch

I have a variable defined with date time format and want to convert it to epoch format in bash script

Input
Var=20170520;

Output:
Epoch format

Comment: Please specify what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: @AravindVoggu  i have  a variable  equal to date time stamp as state above and I didn't find a way to convert  from variable to epoch format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
date=20170520 # i.e. 2017 05 20
date -d "$date" +%s
```

Comment: Question is tagged with `linux`.

Comment: @Cyrus okay, did I miss something? I ran it in a terminal and it worked, please point out if I made a mistake, I'll try to correct it.

Comment: You are using options supported by the BSD version of `date`, not the GNU version used on Linux systems.

Comment: I tried it works but when i add time stamp it failed could you advice me for this  var=201705121234 #2017 05 12  12:12:34

Comment: @Moustafa Looks like it's a little bit tricky and we have to refer to docs. I have only MacOS with me now (BSD). Why don't you just convert hours and minutes into seconds and add it to Epoch seconds returned by `date`?

Comment: for a kicker, `echo "223045" | fold -w2 | paste -sd':' -` this will add semicolon every 2 characters, and `echo "00:20:40" | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }'` this is my oneliner to convert `hh:mm:ss` into seconds.
cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the manpage,

```
date --date=20170520 +%s
```

works (`date --date=20170520` correctly outputs `Sat May 20 00:00:00 YOUR_TIMEZONE 2017`. Alternatively, you might need to tweak the free-form input string.)